# How to put suspend, turn off, reboot buttons on Kubuntu's lock screen?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, kde5

I use 18.04 and there are only two options: log in and switch user.

```
$ inxi -Sxxx
System:    Host: PC Kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.6 (Qt 5.9.5) dm: sddm,sddm
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

[image]

Comment: What would "reset" do?

Comment: @DK Bose I mean reboot.

Comment: Install `inxi` and post the output of `inxi -Sxxx`.

Comment: That's the **lock** screen not the **login** screen! Big difference! How can you expect the same features in both?

Comment: @DK Bose How can I expect ? Easy. On Xubuntu it isn't problem. After waking up on XFCE we have panel at the top of lock screen and  ⏻ button which opens menu, where you can return it to suspend.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
In light of the querist's clarification that it's the lock screen and not the login screen that is the issue the following links maybe of interest:

- [Bug 392798 - Power button actions should be handled from lock screen](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392798)
- [Suspend linux from KDE Plasma 5 lockscreen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441989/61798)

What follows was a response to the original question which mentioned **login** screen.

This is what I see:

[image: login screen]

If that's not what you see, I'm afraid there's something "non-standard" about your system or I could have misunderstood your question.

Comment: That's not what I see, I tried to change desktop theme - still the same. I have only "Different (Switch) User" button. Kubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: @DK Bose, may i know the gdm3 theme name or link for download please.

Comment: @PRATAP Kubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 use ssdm, not gdm3. I'm not in favor of mixing desktop environments but some other users don't seem to have problems!

Comment: @RS are you meaning within a session? Why don't you post an image of what you see and explain exactly when you see it?

Comment: @PRATAP sorry, it should be `sddm`, not `ssdm`!

Comment: @DK Bose added image and inxi -Sxxx